# Converting byte array to memory stream and bitmap causing high memory usage

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have a byte array list. And, I am using it to generate bitmap images via memory stream.

While saving images, memory usage goes very high. And at some point, it causes out of memory exception.

I tried to comment out saving files to see if that causing this problem. Or, called GC manually. Nothing changed, still using high memory. My latest code is like this:

```
List<byte[]> byteArrayList = helper.GetArrayList(); // Gets approximately 10k items.

for (int i = 0; i < byteArrayList.Count; i++)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayList[i]))
    {
        using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms))
        {
            bm.Save(fileLocation);

            bm.Dispose();
        }

        ms.Dispose();
    }

    byteArrayList[i] = null;

    byteArrayList.Remove(byteArrayList[i]);
}

byteArrayList.Dispose();
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Note that calling `Dispose` explicitly isn't needed when it's within a `using` statement already. Setting the list element to null is fairly pointless, and I personally wouldn't bother with the Remove call. (Does `byteArrayList.Dispose()` even compile?)

Comment: Use BufferManager https://www.wintellect.com/pooling-buffers-for-better-memory-management/

Comment: Why is this tagged WPF? Bitmap is a WinForms class.

Comment: @Clemens Because it is a WPF project.

Comment: Then why are you using Bitmap at all? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Clemens Because I have to. I need to save byte arrays as BMP images.

Comment: There is a BmpBitmapEncoder in WPF. No need to use WinForms.

Comment: @Clemens I didn't know that. Will check it. Thanks.

Comment: And obviously your byte arrays already contain encoded bitmap frames. Why not simply call `File.WriteAllBytes`?

Comment: Also, instead of getting a `List<byte[]>`, can you change the method `helper.GetArrayList()` to instead return a `Queue<byte[]>`?

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti Yes, I can change it. Is there any difference between List and Queue?

Comment: @YSFKBDY it will be lighter and also makes your code neater, because you dequeue and you don't need to stay removing from a list. It would have negligible difference to your memory usage though.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti I will try this, too. Thank you.

Comment: I'm also assuming you are not showing the full code. That fileLocation is not changing; you're just overwriting the file each time.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti I forgot to copy that part. I am using i variable as file name.

Comment: @YSFKBDY, submitted the queue version as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and saw that the system cannot collect your garbage in a LOOP. so if you create so many bitmaps in a loop, the memory increases to the peak levels (such 2-3-4 gbs) until garbage collector runs. But when loop ends, the memory level decreases to the normal which is too late. So When I test your code in a BACKGROUNDWORKER instead of main thread, GC doesnt stuck to the loop and runs as it is supposed to and it converts the byte arrays to the bitmaps and save them without any extreme memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the helper method to return a `Queue<T>` instead...

```
Queue<byte[]> byteArrayQueue = helper.GetQueue(); // Gets approximately 10k items.

while (byteArrayQueue.Any())
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayQueue.Dequeue()))
    {
        using (var bm = new Bitmap(ms))
        {
            bm.Save(fileLocation);
        }
    }
}
```